# Running gdb with python

Tags: python, gdb

How would one run `gdb` with python (as opposed to pdb which is pretty straightforward)? For example, if I have this program:

```
# hello.py
def squared(num):
    return num * num

print (squared(4))
```

I can run `gdb` with:

```
$ gdb python
>>> run hello.py

Output/messages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
16
[Inferior 1 (process 12787) exited normally]
>>>
```

It seems to 'work' in that it prints `16` but how would I:

- View the lines of code in the file (`l`)?
- Add a breakpoint from the console (`b`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB is not a Python debugger. GDB is not debugging your Python script. It is debugging *Python*, as in the CPython interpreter executable itself. To GDB, your script is data, not code.

If your Python executable has the necessary debug info, you could set breakpoints in the C source code of CPython, or step through the C source code, but you cannot set breakpoints in your script.

---

For GDB to understand anything about Python, you would have to bolt on a lot of additional code dedicated to understanding Python and adding Python-level breakpoint/line stepping/etc. functionality. As it happens, this extra code already exists!

The [Cython](https://cython.org/) project comes with a [GDB extension](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/debugging.html) allowing mixed Python/C/Cython debugging, because it's a huge pain to try to debug Cython without this kind of functionality. If you need to perform mixed Python/C/Cython debugging, check it out. If you *don't* need to perform mixed debugging, stick to PDB.